# Help with LINQ distinct()

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class called "Orders" that has the property of "City" among others.
I am trying to write a LINQ statement that will get all the distinct cities from a list of orders and return them as a list of strings.

Here is what I have now.

```
public List<string> GetOrderCities(List<Order> orders)
{
   IEnumerable<string> cities= from o in orders
                                select o.City.Distinct().ToString();

   return cities.ToList();

}
```

However, when I run this by passing it a list of orders, I don't seem to be getting anything back. The list is empty that it is returning. The orders I am passing it do all have City values.
Am I just flat out doing this wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're miscalling the `Distinct()` method.

Change it to

```
return orders.Select(o => o.City).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or, using query comprehension syntax:

```
return (from o in orders
        select o.City
       ).Distinct().ToList();
```

(Note parentheses)

Your code calls `Distinct` on the `City` property itself, which is a string.
Since the `String` class implements `IEnumerable<char>`, this method returns an `IEnumerable<char>` containing all of the unique *characters* in the string.
You then call `ToString()` on this enumerable (which is a compiler-generated iterator type from System.Core.dll), which always returns `` System.Linq.Enumerable+d__81`1[System.Char] ``.

Instead, you need to call `.Distinct()` on the `IEnumerable<string>` returned by the `Select` method.

Comment: Oops not sure how that extra C got in there. This is just a typo on the post. The code is select s.City.Distinct().ToString();

Comment: Ok I think I understand. thank you. I will make the change and give it a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can stick with the way in which you are making the call with minor adjustments...you needed to wrap the selection area, then call `Distinct()` on it and then push it to a `List`.

```
List<string> cities = (from o in orders
                       select o.City).Distinct().ToList();

            return cities;
```