# How to filter double elements in an object C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well I have a list which is called employeeList. In the emoloyee Liste there are stored employees with some attributes like id, lastname ...

One of the attributes is Department. Now I want to create Radio Buttons with the Department. As there are more employees per department one department can appear several times but this I'd like to avoid. This is what I already got:

```
for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.Count(); i++)
{
   panDepartments.Children.Add(new RadioButton() { Content = employeeList.ElementAt(i).Department.Distinct()});
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help with LINQ distinct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970850/help-with-linq-distinct)

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the list before you iterate over it. One possibility would be LINQ (i.e. Distinct()) or just do the filtering yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this.

```
//First of all we need to get unique departments.
var departments = employeeList.Select(e => e.Department).Distinct();

//And after that we can create radio buttons and add them as children elements.
foreach(var dep in departments)
{
    panDepartments.Children.Add(new RadioButton() { Content = dep });
}

//foreach loop can be replaced something like this if "panDepartments.Children" 
//supports "AddRange" method
var radioBtns = departments.Select(d => new RadioButton() { Content = dep });
panDepartments.Children.AddRange(radioBtns);
```